# Python how to make curl requests

Tags: python, curl

I need help making the following Curl request in Python:

```
curl --data "username=USERNAME&password=PASSWORD" --header "Authorization: Basic Y2xvdWQtYXBp" -X POST "https://ApiCallUrl/auth/token?grant_type=password" --insecure
```

I have the following code:

```
url = 'https://fakepath'
data = "username=velocity_169234&password=velocity_69234"
header = {'Authorization': b'Basic' + b64encode(('cloud-api').encode('utf-8'))}
data = urlencode(dict(username='USERNAME',password='PASSWORD')).encode('ascii')

response = urlopen(Request(url, data, header))
print(response.info())
```

How do I add the `--insecure` flag?

I am getting this error

```
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:645)>
```

Comment: Python 3 `urlopen` requires you to pass `bytes` instance, not a string. Either pass `data.encode('utf-8')` instead of `data` to `urlopen` method or add `b` prefix to data string definition, e. g. `data = b"username=...&password=..."`

Comment: Use `urllib.parse` library for data parsing. So essentially you have to do this.

Comment: I changed my code to use `urllib.parse` Still error.

Comment: how do i add the --insercure flag into my code?

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835619/urllib-and-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [urllib and "SSL: CERTIFICATE\_VERIFY\_FAILED" Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835619/urllib-and-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-error)

Answer (score 1):

> `curl`
>   -k, --insecure
>   (SSL) This option explicitly allows curl to perform "insecure" SSL connections and transfers.
>   All SSL connections are attempted to be made secure by using the CA certificate bundle installed by default.
>   All connections considered "insecure" will fail unless -k/--insecure is used.

---

> [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#ca-certificates)
>   Requests can also ignore verifying the SSL certificate if you set verify to False:
>
> ```
> requests.get('https://kennethreitz.org', verify=False)
> <Response [200]>
> ```
>
> By default, verify is set to True. Option verify only applies to host certs.

`urlopen` don't have such a parameter.

> **Note**: Disable Certificate Verification is a Security Risk!